# Two interfaces on the same network for redundancy

Tags: networking, linux-networking

Is it possible in linux to use two physical network interfaces on the same local network for redundancy reasons? So if one cable or one interface gets broken everything still keeps working. What is the right approach to solve this problem? Bridge?

Ideally both interfaces would have the same ip address and if one gets broken, linux will just use another interface, is it possible?

Comment: Look up "bonding". RHEL/Centos has something similar named "teaming".

Comment: actually teaming is an alternate driver to bonding for solving the same problems where some "control plane" handling is done in user space rather than all in kernel space (so it requires a teamd daemon). It's probably advocated by RedHat. [Comparison of network teaming and bonding features](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-network-teaming_configuring-and-managing-networking#comparison-of-network-teaming-and-bonding-features_configuring-network-teaming).

Comment: just a suggestion but <Insert your distribution> bonding howto @ google.com, since this question is definitely not business related in your cases.